# Add a new page in Word while automating from VB. net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I've already entirely been able to automate creating a text out of Excel entries in Word. My assignment is to seperate the entries by pages, though. How can I tell the automation to contiue writing on the next page?
My code:

```
    Private Sub AddText(ByVal text As String, oDoc As Word.Document, oPara3 As Word.Paragraph, r As Integer)
    oPara3.Range.Font.Bold = False
    oPara3.Range.Font.Underline = False
    oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)
    oPara3.Range.Text = text
    oPara3.Range.Font.Bold = False
    oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
    oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
End Sub


Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim s As Integer = 0
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oPara3 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oRng

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oRng = oWord.Selection
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    For r = 6 To cmax
        oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)
        oPara3.Range.Text = "Abhängigkeiten von " & sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString
        oPara3.Range.Font.Bold = True
        oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 0
        oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

        If sheet.Range("F" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " ist vom Netzwerk abhängig." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("G" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " ist vom VPN abhängig." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("H" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " ist vom Hypervisor abhängig." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("I" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " ist von der Domäne abhängig." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("J" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " ist von den Netzdiensten abhängig." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("K" & r).Value.ToString = 1 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " hat für das Unternehmen eine geringe Bedeutung." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("K" & r).Value.ToString = 2 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " hat für das Unternehmen eine unterdurchschnittliche Bedeutung." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("K" & r).Value.ToString = 3 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " hat für das Unternehmen eine durchschnittliche Bedeutung." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("K" & r).Value.ToString = 4 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " hat für das Unternehmen eine hohe Bedeutung." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        If sheet.Range("K" & r).Value.ToString = 5 Then
            AddText(sheet.Range("C" & r).Value.ToString & " hat für das Unternehmen eine unersetzliche Bedeutung." & vbNewLine, oDoc, oPara3, r)
        End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

As I said, the code works. I can't find a way to insert new pages though. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oWord.Selection.InsertNewPage()` inside your cycle or where you want to insert new page.
 **Selection.InsertNewPage Method (Word)** - *Inserts a new page at the position of the Insertion Point.* 
For more info look at **Selection Object**:https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/selection-object-word